# Using a date variable in a query to fetch records based on a given date in oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql

I need to write a function in oracle plsql that with take a date as an input and return records from a table for that particular day. If no date is given then fetch the records for current day.

Note that the column (purchase_date) is a timestamp(6) type not null column and has an index on it so I would not like to use trunc() function on the column.

Example value present in purchase_date column is --> 01-DEC-21 06.14.06.388855001 AM

```sql
create or replace FUNCTION getRecordsForDate(
      input_date         DATE  DEFAULT SYSDATE
    ) RETURN sys_refcursor IS
        data_out     SYS_REFCURSOR; 

    BEGIN    

        OPEN data_out FOR
               SELECT
                    p.product_name,
                    p.product_type,
                    p.purchased_by
                FROM
                    product_details p
                WHERE
                    AND p.purchase_date BETWEEN TO_DATE(input_date, 'DD-MON-YY')
                   -- AND TO_DATE('03-MAR-22 23:59:59', 'DD-MON-YY HH24:MI:SS');  --harcoded value works but I need to use input_date
                   AND 'TO_DATE' ||'(''' || input_date || ' 23:59:59''' ||',' || '''YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS''' ||')';
                    
        return data_out;        
    END getRecordsForDate;
```

My concatenation is not working in the last line. It gives me ORA-01858: a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected. Not sure what's wrong here. Would someone be able to help.

Answer (score 3):

- Do not use `TO_DATE` on a `DATE`.
- The last line of the cursor will not work as it is a (concatenated) string literal that cannot be converted to a `TIMESTAMP` or a `DATE`.
- Even if it did work (which it will not), your `purchase_date` is a `TIMESTAMP(6)` data type so you are going to exclude all value from the time `23:59:59.0000001` until `23:59:59.999999`.

You want to use:

```sql
create or replace FUNCTION getRecordsForDate(
  input_date DATE  DEFAULT SYSDATE
) RETURN sys_refcursor
IS
  data_out SYS_REFCURSOR; 
BEGIN    
  OPEN data_out FOR
    SELECT product_name,
           product_type,
           purchased_by
    FROM   product_details
    WHERE  purchase_date >= TRUNC(input_date)
    AND    purchase_date <  TRUNC(input_date) + INTERVAL '1' DAY;

  return data_out;        
END getRecordsForDate;
/
```